# Why would MacBook Pro indicate "not on same network" as iPhone...when that is not the case?

Tags: iphone, mac, error

I have a new MacBook Pro (2015) from apple and I am trying to link with my iPhone so I can make calls from the laptop. I have done this before, with my iMac and other laptops but I keep getting a message (see below) that they are not on the same network...but they are!!! Any thoughts?

[image: IPhone Not Available]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network might me blocking required protocols.

UDP ports 500 and 4500 are required for Wifi Calling.

Other ports and protocols might be needed.

There is a list [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944).

Comment: Thanks for the response. So how do I remedy that? In Network Settings? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have not made changes on your network settings, and if it works on other networks, you need to be the network administrator: the setting might be on the router or firewall on the network you are connected to.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. That helps a lot. There were some changes made by an administrator yesterday so that is likely the issue. I will check with them. I appreciate your help!